# How to correctly use coefficient of restitution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

> A uniform wedge of mass $m$ and triangular cross-section $(AB = BC = CA = 2R)$ is moving with
> a constant velocity $–v \hat
> i$ towards a sphere of radius $R$ fixed on a smooth horizontal table as
> shown in the figure. The wedge makes an elastic collision with the fixed sphere and returns
> along the same path without any rotation. Neglect all friction and suppose that the wedge
> remains in contact with the sphere for a time ∆t. Find the average force $\vec F$
> and also the average
> normal reaction $\vec N$
> exerted by the table on the wedge during the time $∆t$.

[image]

In my solution:

$e= \frac {v_{sep}}{v_{app}} \qquad  \text {(along common normal)}$

$\Rightarrow 1=\frac {v_{sep}}{v \sin 60^\circ}$

Therefore, $v_{sep}=p=\frac {v√3}{2}$

Velocity along the common tangent ,$i.e. q$ , would remain unchanged.

But now, we have a component of velocity along the vertical axis, $i.e. \; \; r$, which is wrong.

[image]

$\lvert \vec p \rvert =\frac {v√3}{2}$, $\lvert \vec q \rvert = \frac {v}{2}$ and $\lvert \vec r \rvert = \frac {v√3}{2}$

$$  \mathbf  { \text {What am I doing wrong?}} $$

(I can see some flaws in my argument but I can't really comprehend it completely)

Comment: You don’t have a “component of velocity along the vertical axis” but you do have a component of _force_ in (both the horizontal and) the vertical direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints only**:

The coefficient of restitution will not give you the answers you are asked. It does relate the velocities before and after collision, but here you are asked to compute forces (also, there are only horizontal velocities and no components in the vertical direction).

The question makes reference to a force acting for a time $\Delta t$. So we can use the definition of impulsive force and how it relates to change in momentum. That is, $$F\Delta t=m\Delta v$$ We can use this relation since the wedge moves in the opposite (negative x) direction after collision. Note that the force has a component in both x and z directions. So for the x-direction, $$F_x \Delta t = m\Delta v=m(v-(-v))=2mv$$ since the collision is elastic. So $$F_x=\frac{2mv}{\Delta t}$$
This is the x-component of the force, and the actual force you are need to calculate will be in the form $$\vec F= F_x \hat{\vec x}+ F_z \hat{\vec z}$$ What remains is to obtain the z-component of the force.

Note that to get the normal force $N$ you need to solve the expression $$N= F_z +mg$$

The wedge is an equilateral triangle meaning all angles are $60^\circ$ and from this information you can deduce $$F_x=Fcos\theta \\ F_z=Fsin\theta $$ but you may need to draw a diagram to get the proper value for $\theta$ and it's not $60^\circ$ as you seemed to have implied above.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to do the same but I was trying to get the velocity of the wedge after collision using coefficient of restitution. Now, I realised that as energy is conserved and no work is done so it must be $v$ only. I still wanted to know if the coefficient of restitution equation valid at all in this situation. I am not sure how I have got $\theta$ wrong. The angle between the common tangent and velocity before collision is 60 while the angle between the common normal and the velocity before collision is 30. So, according to me $v_{app}=v \sin 60^\circ = v \cos 30^\circ$

Comment: Hello. When I use $\theta$ I mean the direction of forces, and not for velocity. Why have you used an angle for velocity? The motion of the wedge is purely in the horizontal direction and so there are no such terms as $vcos(\theta )$ Cheers.

Comment: I thought you are supposed to put in the velocity along the line of action/collision which is the common normal in this case. So, I chose the axis in which common normal is x axis and common tangent is the y axis. And broke the velocity vector into it's x and y component

Comment: But there is motion in the horizontal direction only.